# Mturk api to submit hits

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

Is there is any api available to submit hit on muturk.

Actually I am planning to create an app that will have all the required field of specific hit and worker the hit and the app will submit the hit.

Comment: This is not available.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by *"mturk"* and *"muturk"* you are referring to Amazon's Mechanical Turk service.  They have pretty extensive API documentation available for all of the [Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/).  The Mechanical Turk API is documented at 
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/Welcome.html?r=6748.